# no chat on iPad, YouTube and Chrome for replay of video (Safari does provide chat)

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, ios, chat

On my iPads and iPhone, YouTube chat for replayed videos does not appear in either the YouTube app nor on Chrome.  But when I open them in Safari, the chat appears.  I believe this is a relatively new problem (say, in the past 6 months or so), but it definitely preceeded iOS/iPadOS 17.

Case in point: [This randomly chosen livestream](https://www.youtube.com/live/WzhMPNeeFV8?t=720): will show me a chat immediately in Safari on my iPads and iPhone, all running iOS 17.0.3.  But if I open it by any means in YouTube (meaning via subscriptions page, notifications, et cetera - method makes no difference) or on Chrome iOS or iPadOS, no chat appears.  I believe, but cannot currently verify, that the chat will appear on macOS 16/17 Chrome.  (Not at home, so cannot check.  Will update question Wednesday if not answered.)

Is there a setting I can use to enable chat for replays (especially in YouTube app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They merged the comments and live chats. Swipe to the left from comments to see the live chat.

Comment: YAY!!!!  I'm so happy!  Thank you for the response; I was afraid they're taking it away.  Although I must say I think it was a poor move (and confusing) I am happy that it's not gone.